# Checkbox text value receive on checkbox check in livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, livewire-3

In my Livewire View

```blade
@foreach ($diagnosisList as $row)
    <div class="col-6 mb-2">
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
            <label class="form-check mb-0 w-120px">
                <input wire:model.debounce.1000ms='diagnoses.{{ $row->id }}'
                    data-name="{{ $row->name }}"
                    class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="{{ $row->id }}">
                <span class="form-check-label font-13 fw-medium">{{ $row->name }}</span>
            </label>
            
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

In my Livewire Class (controller):

```
public function updatedDiagnoses($value, $id)
{

}
```

In livewire, i need to get $row->name in updatedDiagnoses() for checked event and push them into array.
How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should post the format of your data, however I assume you have a *$diagnosisList* array containing the models and a *$diagnosis* array containing checkbox values ​​indexed by record id

The only way for your configuration is to read the row from DB :

```
public function updatedDiagnosis($value, $id)
{
   $name = Diagnosis::find($id)->name; // I suppose you have a Diagnosis model
}
```

I can't understand the ".debounce.1000ms"
If you are using Livewire 3 perhaps you should change it with *.live* to let the backend call happen on change:

```
<input wire:model.live="diagnosis.{{ $row->id }}" ..... >
```

It would be also advisable to add a wire:key in the @foreach content:

```blade
@foreach ($diagnosisList as $row)
   <div class="col-6 mb-2" wire:key="diag-{{ $row->id }}">
      .....
   </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: In updatedDiagnosis() method can I get name without query? Actually I want to avoid to run db query each time checkbox is checked.

Comment: From what I can see, no.
Post a more complete situation for a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a public property in your livewire to hold the array of checked diagnosis names and then update `updatedDiagnoses` to add/remove the diagnosis name from `$checkedDiagnoses` base on whether the checkbox is checked/unchecked. You need to pass both value and name of the diagnosis to the `updatedDiagnoses` using js and then create the `updatedCheckedDiagnoses` in your livewire:

**Livewire Class (controller)**

```
namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class YourComponent extends Component
{
    public $diagnoses = [];
    public $checkedDiagnoses = [];

    public function mount()
    {
        // Initialize the diagnoses array with default values if needed
        foreach ($this->diagnosisList as $diagnosis) {
            $this->diagnoses[$diagnosis->id] = false;
        }
    }

    public function updateCheckedDiagnoses($id, $name)
    {
        if ($this->diagnoses[$id]) {
            // Checkbox is checked, add the diagnosis name to the array
            $this->checkedDiagnoses[] = $name;
        } else {
            // Checkbox is unchecked, remove the diagnosis name from the array
            $index = array_search($name, $this->checkedDiagnoses);
            if ($index !== false) {
                unset($this->checkedDiagnoses[$index]);
            }
        }
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.your-component', [
            'diagnosisList' => Diagnosis::all(), // Assuming Diagnosis is your model
        ]);
    }
}
```

**Livewire View**

```
<div>
    @foreach ($diagnosisList as $row)
        <div class="col-6 mb-2">
            <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                <label class="form-check mb-0 w-120px">
                    <input wire:change="updateCheckedDiagnoses({{ $row->id }}, '{{ $row->name }}')"
                           class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="{{ $row->id }}">
                    <span class="form-check-label font-13 fw-medium">{{ $row->name }}</span>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Comment: Although this seems like the most obvious solution, I don't think it makes sense to pass the *name* from the browser to the backend. It should be clear that every time a checkbox is clicked, an AJAX call is made, in which *name* could also be tampered with. The possibility of avoiding all these calls should be considered, but without seeing the rest of the code it is very difficult.